# Adding swatch to Library InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, swatches, adobe-library

I am following a tutorial that uses InDesign CC. I am currently practicing on InDesign CS6. The tutorial is talking about CC libraries. I added a new library to my CS6 document and created new swatches which I would like to add to my library but it will not allow me.

I am wondering if this is a feature not included in CS6? And how I would add swatches to a library I have created in the CS6 version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: CC was the version of the Creative Suite that came _after_ CS6, when everything started moving to the cloud (hence Creative Cloud instead of Creative Suite); CC libraries belong to CC, not CS – they hadn’t been invented yet when CS6 was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC Libraries are *different* than CS6 libraries.

**CC libraries** can contain many things - essentially anything that can traditional be saved externally - swatches, object styles, cell styles, table styles, etc. CC combined all externally savable items into one common location.

**CS6 Libraries** merely contain saved *objects*. With CS6 you create an object and then add that *object* to the Library. You *could* merely create a rectangle filled with your color, that rectangle can then be added to a CS6 library for later access. CS6 Libraries *can't* contain swatches or styles or anything which is merely a *definition*, Library items have to be objects.

The actual color swatch itself can't be saved to a "library" in CS6 but can be saved to an .ase file - which is a saved external file containing merely swatch definitions. When you load an .ase file, it merely populates the Swatch Panel, it doesn't open or populate any "library" panel directly.

So **yes**, there is a difference in Library operations between CS6 and CC versions of InDesign.